# Why was my answer locked?

Tags: discussion, moderation

I answered to this question [Best Approach for subnetting/VLANing traffic?](https://serverfault.com/questions/458808/best-approach-for-subnetting-vlaning-traffic/458811#458811).

You can see that some didn't agree, and voiced their opinion...even if more and more security holes are found in VoIP systems relying on VLAN to segregate.

There's even a [OSS tool](http://voiphopper.sourceforge.net/) available to "hop" from one VLAN to the Voice Vlan.

There's also the fact that QoS won't kick in unless a link is saturated.

Plus having Voice and Data on the same infrastructure just added a single point of failure for both networks.

Anyway, my answer was flagged and is now only considered for historical reasons.

My question is, are we now a community that will only offer one way of setting things up? If you don't agree with that way then hit the highway?

I thought we where allowed to express opinions. Mine is that relying on VLAN and one switching network is not optimal for every situations.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer was locked *temporarily* while I cleaned up some flammable comments. That comment thread was looking to get outright acrimonious so I dropped a temp-lock on it to keep the combatants separated while I got language straightened out. I then removed the lock, which looks to be the case right now.

The question doesn't show as locked when I look at it as a not-logged-in user. I'm not sure why you see it as locked, it shouldn't be. It was only locked about 5-10 minutes.

Comment: Thanks for the clarifications.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry. I just re-locked it. I understand this is effectively punishing you for others' bad behavior. Unfortunately there's no other way to prevent the discussion chain that's been building.

Comment: That's totally fine by me.